# How to format bodyPart of javax.mail message

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, javax

I am using the javax.mail API to send error messages from a Java cron job to my private inbox. Upon error, I pass the stacktrace to my email body. The problem is that the Java code structure is not preserved by this process. The line breaks are apparently ignored. When the emails arrive, the body looks like this:

```
java.lang.Exception: BackUp folder for BatchClass D_DE_KABI_DELIVERY_NOTES_V03 not found. at FncApplicationLevelScript.importFromMultiFolders(FncApplicationLevelScript.java:378) at FncApplicationLevelScript.execute(FncApplicationLevelScript.java:151) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor431.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at com.ephesoft.dcma.script.compiler.DynamicCodeCompiler$MyInvocationHandler.invoke(DynamicCodeCompiler.java:364) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy256.execute(Unknown Source) at com.ephesoft.dcma.script.ScriptExecutor.executeApplicationScript(ScriptExecutor.java:305) at com.ephesoft.dcma.script.service.ScriptServiceImpl.executeApplicationScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:115) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor427.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:58) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy175.executeApplicationScript(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor424.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269) at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:321) at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:111) at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216) at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
```

whereas I would like it to look like this:

```
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
C:\Ephesoft\SharedFolders\BC4E47\script- 
config\BC4E47_batchClassProperties.properties (The system cannot find the 
file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at fncBatchUtils.FncBatchUtils.loadPropertyFile(FncBatchUtils.java:140)
at fncBatchUtils.FncBatchUtils.<init>(FncBatchUtils.java:94)
at fncBatchUtils.FncMail.<init>(FncMail.java:247)
at ScriptAutomaticValidation.execute(ScriptAutomaticValidation.java:79)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor910.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.ephesoft.dcma.script.compiler.DynamicCodeCompiler$MyInvocationHandler.invoke(DynamicCodeCompiler.java:364)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy258.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.ephesoft.dcma.script.ScriptExecutor.extractBatch(ScriptExecutor.java:455)
... 122 more
```

For better readability, I would like the Java code structure and especially the line breaks to be preserved.

I currently extract the error message like this:

```
try { ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
    String errorMessage = "Error occured...";
    String bodyText = sw.toString();
    String from = "capturing-development@xxx.com";
    sendMail(errorMessage, bodyText , from);
}
```

Inside the `sendMail` method, the `bodyPart` is set to contain the error stacktrace (contained in `bodyText`) like this:

```
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
String htmlMessage = "<p> " + bodyText + " </p><br>";
messagePart.setContent(htmlMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);
message.setContent(multipart);
```

Is there any way I can tell my message object to format the bodyPart in a readable way (i.e. Java code format)?

Comment: Why not just send the message as plain text instead of HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in HTML whitespace and linebreaks are ignored. You should try replacing newline characters with `<br/>` tags before adding to the message body, or insert `<br/>` after each closing parenthesis `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()` from apache commons lang which can take care of adjacent whitespaces and alos other special characters

Answer (score 0):

Why not use HtmlEmail email api - use StringBuffer for HTML sample from [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/HtmlEmail.html)

```
HtmlEmail he = new HtmlEmail();
 File img = new File("my/image.gif");
 PNGDataSource png = new PNGDataSource(decodedPNGOutputStream); // a custom class
 StringBuffer msg = new StringBuffer();
 msg.append("<html><body>");
 msg.append("<img src=cid:").append(he.embed(img)).append(">");
 msg.append("<img src=cid:").append(he.embed(png)).append(">");
 msg.append("</body></html>");
 he.setHtmlMsg(msg.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example you can add html as Body Content, attach files also.

```
        String text = "html tags";

        Multipart mainMultiPart = new MimeMultipart();  
        MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        mimeBodyPart.setText(text);
        mimeBodyPart.setContent(text, "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1""text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
        mainMultiPart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);

        java.io.File file = null;

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPartFile = new MimeBodyPart();
        FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource(file);      
        messageBodyPartFile.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));       
        String fileName = fds.getName();        
        messageBodyPartFile.setFileName(fileName);      
        mainMultiPart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPartFile);     

        javax.mail.Message message = null;      
        message.setContent(mainMultiPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem by using these tags:

`String htmlMessage = "<p><pre><code> " + bodyText + " </pre></code></p><br>";`

Comment: If that's what you're doing, why not just send it as text/plain?